# How to control the cl.exe command that nvcc builds

Tags: python-2.7, visual-studio-2013, cuda, nvcc

I just installed CUDA 6.5, VS2013 Community Edition, and pyCUDA. I already had python 2.7.8 installed. I am new to CUDA and VS2013 development but not python. I verified my CUDA install by building some of the CUDA VS2013 sample solutions as both 32- and 64-bit so things work up to that point.

Now I'm trying to verify my pyCUDA install by running this test program.

```
### from: http://documen.tician.de/pycuda/tutorial.html
import pycuda.gpuarray as gpuarray
import pycuda.driver as cuda
import pycuda.autoinit
import numpy as np

# copy to gpu
a_gpu = gpuarray.to_gpu(np.random.randn(4,4).astype(np.float32))

# double it
a_doubled = (2 * a_gpu).get()
print('a_doubled', a_doubled)
```

When run, it produces this error:

```
[snip]
  File "B:\Anaconda2\lib\site-packages\pycuda-2014.1-py2.7-win-amd64.egg\pycuda\compiler.py", line 250, in do_compile
    return compile_plain(source, options, keep, nvcc, cache_dir)
  File "B:\Anaconda2\lib\site-packages\pycuda-2014.1-py2.7-win-amd64.egg\pycuda\compiler.py", line 132, in compile_plain
    stderr=stderr.decode("utf-8", "replace"))
CompileError: nvcc compilation of e:\temp\cb4\tmpadhjeh\kernel.cu failed
[command: nvcc -cubin -keep -cudart shared -arch sm_52 -m64 -Ib:\anaconda2\lib\site-packages\pycuda-2014.1-py2.7-win-amd64.egg\pycuda\cuda -keep kernel.cu]
[stdout:kernel.cu]
[stderr:
'B:\VisualStudioCom2013\VC\bin\amd64"\cl.exe @kernel.cpp1.ii.res > "kernel.cpp1.ii' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
operable program or batch file.]
```

Note the extraneous double quotes in the cl.exe command which are causing the error. Without them I can manually run `B:\VisualStudioCom2013\VC\bin\amd64\cl.exe @kernel.cpp1.ii.res > kernel.cpp1.ii`. It completes just fine and a valid kernel.cpp1.ii is generated.

Is there some way to control the cl.exe command that nvcc builds? Nothing in the nvcc manual jumped out at me, but with all those options I certainly might've have missed it.

Also posted [in this Nvidia developers forum](https://devtalk.nvidia.com/default/topic/801185/cuda-6-5-nvcc-building-invalid-cl-exe-command-line-with-extra-double-quotes/).

Comment: What happens if you run the nvcc compilation command manually? Does it generate the same error?

Comment: I get the same error. Also tried removing all options except `-Ib:\anaconda2\lib\site-packages\pycuda-2014.1-py2.7-win-amd64.egg\pycuda\cuda` but that didn't help.

Comment: Have a look at your `nvcc.profile` file and see whether it contains the malformed path. There is a discussion in the nvcc manual of how that file works.

Comment: The problem is not there - I'm using the default profile from the nvcc manual.

Comment: When you ask the same question on multiple forums, it's polite to provide a link to the existing discussion: https://devtalk.nvidia.com/default/topic/801185/cuda-6-5-nvcc-building-invalid-cl-exe-command-line-with-extra-double-quotes/

Comment: Totally agree - post updated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is a bug in nvcc for CUDA 6.5. After following @talonmies suggestion to look through nvcc.profile, I started trying combinations of profile settings and command line options. I narrowed it down to this: when --keep is on the command line AND compiler-bindir is in the nvcc.profile, the malformed cl.exe compile command that includes double quotes is generated. The solution for keeping intermediate files is to put cl.exe in the path and remove compiler-bindir from nvcc.profile. Logged as a bug to NVIDIA.

**UPDATE:**
The problem does not manifest in CUDA 7.0.